# Linq when we create object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
public  bool DeleteLoc(int Location_Id)
{
    DataClassesLocationDataContext dc = new DataClassesLocationDataContext();

    Location loc = dc.Locations.Single(u => u.Location_id == Location_Id);
    dc.Locations.DeleteOnSubmit(loc);

    dc.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
} 


public bool DeleteComp(int Company_Id)
{
      DataClassesLocationDataContext dc = new DataClassesLocationDataContext();

      **Company com  = dc.Comp.Single(u => u.Location_id == Location_Id);**
}
```

In this line it does not show like as Locations in previous code

why it can not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `linq to sql` than its must be name of the class that you can see in you **DBML** file generated by Visual Studio...

if i m getting you correctly

```
Location loc = dc.Locations.Single(u => u.Location_id == Location_Id);
```

here in this line Locations is set of collection contains location object.

```
Company com  = dc.Comp.Single(u => u.Location_id == Location_Id)
```

in this line same as locations Comp is set of collection contains company object. is it cannt same as location object...**So in second case it will display property of Company object not of location object.**